# How to modify font-changer's html code of open journal system?

Tags: html, css

I am changing open journal system's css codes. On the side bar, there are a few divs which contain some parts. One of those contains three links about changing font size of the page (larger font size-default font size-smaller font size) at the bottom. The links layout was made side-by-side using

```
float: left;
```

Then I made those divs more stylish. I have added the following rules:

```
border-radius: 8px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
margin: 10px auto;
background: rgb(254,254,254);
```

But because of the links' float:left rule, div's height seems not enough. So I have decided to add the line below right after the three links I mentioned before:

```
<div  style="clear:both"></div>
```

I have searched any files in entire web site but I could not find where it is. 
Is somebody knows where I can add that html code after three links?

You can see the image of my current problem.
[image: My problem]

As you can see on the image buttons/links go out of the borders of the div. I want to add the line above to fix this.

Comment: This clearfix method is old. [Read about this one.](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) Just add this solution to conteiner's class of floated elements.

Comment: You can also just float the container element as well, or give it `overflow:hidden` – both will trigger the inclusion of floated child elements into the element’s height calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding oveflow has solved my problem. 
Thanks CBroe

```
border-radius: 8px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
margin: 10px auto;
background: rgb(254,254,254);
overflow:hidden;
```

[image: Problem has gone away]

### Another Approach

But I have found another solution eventhough  nd_macias says it is an old approach.

I have found the file public_html/lib/pkp/js/fontController.js

Then I have found the following  at lines 32 to 35:

```
smallFontHtml = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='smallFont' title='" + minCaption +"'>" + minCaption + "</a> ";
defFontHtml = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='defaultFont' title='" + defCaption +"'>" + defCaption + "</a> ";
largeFontHtml = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='largeFont' title='" + maxCaption +"'>" + maxCaption + "</a> ";
$(container).html(smallFontHtml + defFontHtml + largeFontHtml);
```

Then modified it to the below:

```
smallFontHtml = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='smallFont' title='" + minCaption +"'>" + minCaption + "</a> ";
defFontHtml = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='defaultFont' title='" + defCaption +"'>" + defCaption + "</a> ";
largeFontHtml = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='largeFont' title='" + maxCaption +"'>" + maxCaption + "</a> ";
clearFix = "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
$(container).html(smallFontHtml + defFontHtml + largeFontHtml + clearFix);
```

This can be dealed as another solution.